# Default Search_Path Variable Stuck After Installing Postgis with Homebrew on Mac

Tags: macos, postgis, homebrew

After installing postgresql and postgis on my mac ...

```
brew install postgres
brew install postgis
```

...I have a search_path which is stuck on being just set to "postgis".  The value in the postgresql.conf file is ignored or overwritten, it doesn't even mention postgis by default.  Also if I run commands such as ...

```
ALTER USER ken SET search_path TO postgis,schema1,schema2;
ALTER DATABASE coneddb SET search_path TO postgis,shema1,schema2;
```

...then the path is still set to just "postgis" upon starting a new connection.  What am I missing that is overriding my search_path and won't let me override it with user or database specific settings?

Answer (score 0):

Uggggh.  When everything else failed I tried a reboot of the machine.  Bingo.  No idea why a reboot would have been required here but that seems to have done the trick.  My search_path is now what it is in the postgresql.conf file.  And yes, I had stopped and started the service to reload the conf file.  In fact, I had even made sure that changes to the conf file were being recognized by changing the port number and proving that when I brought postgresql back up it was listening on the specified port and not on the original port.  So, really no idea what was going on here.